# Automatically send outlook appointment to someone else's calendar from excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Relatively new to excel macros and what not so looking for a little bit of help. I have written a piece of code to automatically add a list of calendar events in excel in to my outlook calendar, I was wondering how I would go about automatically forwarding/sending these on to someone else's calendar (that I have access to).

One other thing I am struggling with is I am receiving an error whenever I hit a blank cell. I was wondering how I can make the code stop whenever a blank cell is hit **Thanks @AndrasDork for answering this part of the question**

Thanks!

```
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutItem As Object
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xRg = Range("A2:G25")
    For I = 1 To xRg.Rows.Count
        Set xOutItem = xOutApp.createitem(1)
        Debug.Print xRg.Cells(I, 1).Value
        xOutItem.Subject = xRg.Cells(I, 1).Value
        xOutItem.Location = xRg.Cells(I, 2).Value
        xOutItem.Start = xRg.Cells(I, 3).Value
        xOutItem.Duration = xRg.Cells(I, 4).Value
        If Trim(xRg.Cells(I, 5).Value) = "" Then
            xOutItem.BusyStatus = 2
        Else
            xOutItem.BusyStatus = xRg.Cells(I, 5).Value
        End If
        If xRg.Cells(I, 6).Value > 0 Then
            xOutItem.ReminderSet = True
            xOutItem.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = xRg.Cells(I, 6).Value
        Else
            xOutItem.ReminderSet = False
        End If
        xOutItem.Body = xRg.Cells(I, 7).Value
        xOutItem.Save
        Set xOutItem = Nothing
    Next
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Sub ResolveName()  
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace  
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient  
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 

 Set myNamespace = xOutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev")  

 myRecipient.Resolve  

 If myRecipient.Resolved Then  
   Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
 End If 

End Sub  

Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 

 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 

 CalendarFolder.Display  
End Sub
```

Comment: @AndrasDorko I apologize I didn’t know that, I will resolve and change back when I’m back at my desktop, apologies!

Comment: @AndrasDorko resolved so that the original question shows now as well, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering how I would go about automatically forwarding/sending these on to someone else's calendar (that I have access to)

The Outlook object model provides the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm765)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared Calendar folder). For example:

```
Sub ResolveName()  
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace  
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient  
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 

 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev")  

 myRecipient.Resolve  

 If myRecipient.Resolved Then  
   Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
 End If 

End Sub  

Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 

 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 

 CalendarFolder.Display  
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried running this and didnt work...is there a specific place I have to insert this relative to the rest of my code

Comment: did you get any error? what line of code exactly fails?

Comment: Getting an error on the "Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAP") line. Its saying "object doenst support this property or method.

Comment: Use `xOutApp` instead of `Application`.

Comment: Now Im receiving "Object Required" on the same line

Comment: Make sure the `xOutApp` object was instantiated before.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, Ive added the most update code to the question so you can let me know.

Comment: `Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`

Comment: Yes this is being done, its in line 5...does it need to be in the same sub?